# Youtube API how to get video info

Tags: api, video, youtube

When you right click on the video and say "show video info", there is popup that shows fps, frames dropped etc in real time with a timestamp.

I tried to look in the API documentation but couldn't find how this data could be retrieved.

I would like to store this realtime video info data in a file and do post analysis based on time to understand video streaming quality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, as of now there is no functional method to get the "show video info" information through the YouTube API, or it's RSS feed.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. :(

Answer (score 6):

You're going to have to use the new v3 API. You can sign up for a YouTube key here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

To get the actual video info you can then use this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={VIDEO_ID}&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics &key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Note that this answer no longer works. See [Dex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44351277/453435) below.

All the data an app can see about a video is parsed in XML (or JSON if you prefer) using this URL:

> **XML:** http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/###########?v=2
>
> **JSON:** http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/###########?v=2&alt=json-in-script

Just replace ########## with the `?v=` numbers of your video. For instance: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/rznYifPHxDg?v=2

Comment: Google has made this method no longer available.